# In trying to render a tanstack table in my Nuxt3 app, I get `$data.somes.getRowModel is not a function`

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, tanstack

I am trying to render a tanstack table in my Nuxt3 app and facing this ...

```
500

$data.somes.getRowModel is not a function
```

Here's the relevant code ...

```
<template>
  <div>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="row in somes.getRowModel().rows" :key="row.id">
      <td v-for="cell in row.getVisibleCells()" :key="cell.id">
        <FlexRender
          :render="cell.column.columnDef.cell"
          :props="cell.getContext()"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useVueTable } from '@tanstack/vue-table';
import { FlexRender } from '@tanstack/vue-table';

const options = {}
const table = useVueTable(options);

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      somes: '',
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.somes = await $fetch(
      'https://xxxxx.xx/somes', {
      }
    )
  },
}
</script>
```

Obviously I am missing something. Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: template code is executed synchronously, but the data used in your template is retrieved async. at the moment the component is created, `v-for="row in somes.getRowModel().rows"` is invalid because `somes` is initially just an empty string.  you need to put a v-if to not render this code until `somes` actually has a valid value

Comment: it would also be better if the v-for had an actual array assigned to it, instead of an array derived from a function call...

Comment: Ok, so by using `somes: {}` in the return block and `<p v-for="some in somes" :key="some.name"> {{ some.name }}</p>` within the template block, it works fine. However, replacing the `<p>...</p>` by `<tbody>...</tbody>` doesn't - leads to `$data.somes.getRowModel is not a function`

Comment: My advice was to use [v-if](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html) to prevent rendering (and rendering related errors) until `some` is a non-empty object.  I think your original code would work fine with just `v-if="Object.keys(somes).length > 0"` placed on the parent div, though do still change initilization to `somes: {}`

Comment: Alright, I have now used `v-if` per your advice and don't see the error anymore. However, I see an empty page now and the Terminal shows this line ...
`[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: FlexRender
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.`

Comment: What does your `somes` data actually look like?  Judging by the [vue example](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/vue/basic), `somes` is expected to be the return value of `useVueTable()` (in the example "somes" is called "table").  It looks like the only thing you're using `useVueTable` for is an unused `table` variable.  You likely need to supply your `somes` data to this composable.

Comment: It is a simple `array` resulting from a GET to an external server - `curl -s https://xxxxx.xx/somes -d {} | jq ".[].name"` - Output of which is ... `"John" "Jack" "George"`

Comment: BTW, I have deleted the lines for `options` and `table`

Comment: so you can see how trying to use `somes`, which is a simple array of strings, won't work in your template where you have `somes.getRowModel().rows`?  there is no getRowModel function...  This function comes from supplying your tables initial data to the `useVueTable` composable like I said.

Comment: Just to clarify - The `GET` call returns an `array` of `jsons`. In each `json` within the `array` of `jsons`, there is a `name` field (key).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255977/discussion-between-naga-vijayapuram-and-yoduh).

Comment: It's a minor nitpick correction you've made to what I said and doesn't help move the conversation forward.  My point still stands -- you don't have a getRowModel function in `some`.  **You need to use `useVueTable` with your initial table data for it to be usable in your template**, just like how it is shown in the tanstack documentation and fully working example code using static data.  The difference in using fetched data should be minor.  Sorry I can't join for chat, I think you probably need more help than I can give.